# print_term writing to a file in PROLOG

Tags: prolog

In this mcve]

```
test :-                         
  tell('junk.txt'),
  print_term(
       examples([this,is,a,really,long,example,list],
             [made,of,lists,atoms,and,including,terms(involving,parentheses,like,this)]),
       []),
  told.
```

SWI-PROLOG does print the term to the screen neatly in the `print_term` way, but won't print it to the file. How do I redirect the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`current_output/1`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=current_output/1) to get the current Stream and then pass it to [`print_term/2`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=prolog_pretty_print%3Aprint_term/2) in its `Options` parameter:

```
test :-                         
  tell('junk.txt'),
  current_output(Stream),
  print_term(
       examples([this,is,a,really,long,example,list],
             [made,of,lists,atoms,and,including,terms(involving,parentheses,like,this)]),
       [output(Stream)]),
  told.
```

I believe all those Edinburgh style predicates that deal with files are in maintenance mode and you now may prefer to use [ISO stream predicates](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=isoIO).